# Multistage Dockerfile Python

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

so I got trouble here, I've deployed my multistage dockerfile with `python:3.8-slim-buster`, but I can't access this URL ? is there something wrong with my Dockerfile ?

```sh
# Build Image
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster as builder

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-dev python3-pip git
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -U setuptools
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app

# Production Image
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster as app

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENTRYPOINT gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:1500 --workers 1 --threads 8 main:app --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornH11Worker --preload --timeout 60 --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm
```

This is how I run my Docker:

```sh
sudo docker build -t priceengine .
sudo docker run -dp 1500:1500 priceengine
sudo docker start 2d7f96017801
```

So, my `# Production Image` was correct ?

Comment: Please add your `docker` commands and all output related to the error to your question.

Comment: @KlausD. I have added my `docker` commands. From the output, it got `This site can’t be reached`, it can't be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your app depends on the installed packages, if so it will not work with a multistage built. Multistage builds are only helpful to avoid adding build-time dependencies to the final image. Here you need the `apt` packages and `requirements.txt` packages at runtime (`ENTRYPOINT`). Just use a normal Dockerfile for this (no multistage).

Comment: Updated, I use these line of code to run this docker

Comment: Cool, thanks. I've updated my answer also.

Comment: So, before that, is my `# Production Image` was right?  The reason why I tried to use this `Multistage docker` is to reduce my docker image size, it got `2.56GB` size (Too Large). I have searched that to reduce the image size is use python Alpine (But some researchers say that is not recommended if python use many libraries), and the other say that use `Multistage docker`.

Comment: Best way to make it smaller is to go through the requirements.txt and see if you can re-arrange something and remove things that are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a line with `EXPOSE 1500` before your `ENTRYPOINT`. This exposes the port from the docker container to your host system. Can you access it then?

Edit: Also not unimportant, how are you running your Docker container? Can you show your `docker run` command?

Comment: Updated, I have added my `docker` command. EXPOSE 1500 is needed to open the port ? I have open this port with `sudo ufw allow 1500`